# Rain arrows in random positions within bounds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I summon arrows from the sky in a random position but at the same time to be inside the coordinates that I want?

For example, if I use the following, will that summon an arrow in that position?

```
/summon Arrow x y z
```

I want it to be summoned in a random X, Y, Z but at the same time within a specific position of four points:

```
{x1,y1,z1} & {x2,y2,z2} & {x3,y3,z3} & {x4,y4,z4}
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
setblock ~ ~1 ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {
    SpawnCount:1,
    SpawnRange:16,
    Delay:-1,
    MinSpawnDelay:1,
    MaxSpawnDelay:1,
    MaxNearbyEntities:32767,
    RequiredPlayerRange:32767,
    SpawnPotentials:[
        {
            Type:"Arrow",
            Weight:1,
            Properties:{
                Motion:[0.0,-1.0,0.0]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This will create a MobSpawner, spawning falling arrows at random in a square around it. The square is 3 high and 2*SpawnRange wide. On the current settings it will spawn one arrow per tick, you can increase SpawnCount to have more, or Min/MaxSpawnDelay to have less.

Of course this leaves us with a very derpy spawner up in the sky. The next step is to put it underground, and add a /fill clock that triggers a command block, teleporting arrows in the spawn square up in the air :

```
tp @e[type=arrow,x=...,y=...,z=...,dx=...,dy=...,dz=...] ~ 128 ~
```

Comment: I thought there was a way to get the arrows to spawn in the sky while having the command block in the ground.  Also, isn't it possible to make the spawner transparent?

Comment: @MBraedley Nope. I tried with MinecartSpawners as well, but they aren't affected by potion effects. But my last paragraph gives you the solution : spawn the arrows underground around the spawner, _then_ teleport them up. Relative coordinates ensure they keep their horizontal randomness.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I just thought there would have been a more elegant solution that didn't require the use of a fast clock.

Comment: @MBraedley that's the best you can do, spawners give you randomness but their bounds are hard-coded. Don't worry though, that command won't be a noticeable strain.

Comment: I think there's a way to MCEdit spawners around without changing the spawning coordinates. I can't watch it now, but I think SethBling explained it in his explanation of Mt. Dinnerbone.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for can be done by creating a customized Monster Spawner. It can be customized to spawn things other than monsters, and to activate even if the players are far away.

The key thing a spawner gets you is randomized spawning locations.

Here's a command for a command block (it's too long for chat) which will create such a spawner:

> /setblock ~ ~13 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 destroy {EntityId:Arrow,SpawnData:{Motion:[0.0,-0.25,0.0]},SpawnCount:15,SpawnRange:15,Delay:0,MinSpawnDelay:1,MaxSpawnDelay:1,RequiredPlayerRange:15,MaxNearbyEntities:150}

The key things I learned while getting this to work:

- You *must* specify `SpawnData` for the arrows, or the arrows simply won't spawn at all.
- For some reason, the initial `Delay` value matters; when I had it higher than 0, it would only spawn arrows once, even though the `MaxSpawnDelay` was low.

Extra bits:

- The `RequiredPlayerRange` and location are set so that it'll activate when you're under it.
- The `Motion` makes the arrows be moving downward immediately, rather than appearing motionless and starting to fall.

If you want the rain of arrows to be controllable by redstone rather than player proximity, then set the `RequiredPlayerRange` to a large number, and use `setblock` commands to create or destroy the spawner as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Make a clock with command blocks around it.

Set each block to summon an arrow in a specific position, and set up the specific positions to make it appear random.